# Spring Data: Adding custom behavior to single repositories

Tags: java, spring-data

I've tried to add a custom behaviour to Spring Data repository, but it didn't work.

Dao:

```
public interface Dao extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, DaoCustom {

}
```

DaoCustom:

```
public interface DaoCustom {

    User create(User user);
}
```

DaoCustomImpl:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DaoCustomImpl implements DaoCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

MainClass:

```
public class SpringDataJPAMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RootConfig.class);
        Dao dao = context.getBean(Dao.class);

    }
}
```

When I run MainClass, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property create found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at testSpringDataJPA.config.SpringDataJPAMain.main(SpringDataJPAMain.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property create found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:64)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 11 more
```

What's wrong? According to Spring's [tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing your custom repository in Spring Data Repository, you have to follow Spring naming conventions. So try this:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DaoImpl implements DaoCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Your custom repository implementation class name should be 'MainRepositoryClassName' + 'Impl'